# int* dynamic realloc fails at size 8 in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, memory-management, dynamic

I'd like to store integers in a dynamically allocated int array

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    int *arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); //Size 1 int

    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) //loop for inserting elements
    {
        arr[i] = i; //insert i element
        printf("%d\n", i + 2); //prints arr size + 1
        arr = (int*) realloc(arr, i + 2); //realloc int* size + 1
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the result:

```
~/eda/practica7/ $ ./test
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted
```

No matter what I do, realloc for my int* arr ALWAYS stops at size 8.

I already checked that there's enough memory available and it seems like it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: `arr = (int*) realloc(arr, i + 2);` should be `arr = (int*) realloc(arr,(i + 2)*sizeof(int));`

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer thanks! it worked.

sizeof() returns a number or an actual block of memory? I'm confused as because I don't know for example if let's say `arr = (int*) realloc(arr,(i + 2)*4);` would be the same as `arr = (int*) realloc(arr,(i + 2)*sizeof(int));`

Thanks for the help

Comment: The `sizeof` operator evaluated to the size of the given object or type in bytes.  So if you want to allocate space for `x` objects of type `t`, you want to allocate `x * sizeof(t)` bytes.

Comment: @Adolf You're right, `sizeof()` returns a number, `sizeof(int)` and `4` are almost always the same (depends on the C implementation), but it's always better to use `sizeof(int)`, you should not assume the size of any datatype.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer thanks! My question it's more directed towards why was it stopping until 8? I imagine that number has to do with the size of bytes (hence why sizeof() it's used), I understand that. What I don't understand it's why it didn't stop at the second loop because technically the arr only had size for 1 int at first but not for the second, nevermind 7 int. It always seemed to give up at 8.

Comment: @Adolf: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is already invoked in the second iteration of the loop, when you write to the memory buffer out of bounds. Whether your program crashes sooner or later or not at all depends on the internal details of your compiler and/or operating system and maybe also depends on the compiler settings, and the results will likely be different on different platforms. Therefore, there is no point in discussing why something happens once undefined behavior has been invoked, because it is, by definition, unpredictable.

Comment: @Adolf: Maybe this analogy will help you understand better: Your question is like asking the following: "When I drill a 20 centimeter hole into the front of my car, the car continues to work. But when I instead drill a 40 centimeter hole into my car, it stops working. Why is it so?" The answer to this question and to your question is the same: It depends on the inner workings of the car/compiler/operating system. The advice in both cases also is the same: Stop invoking undefined behavior (for example by drilling holes into your car)!

Comment: `arr = (int*) realloc(arr, i + 2);` --> `arr = realloc(arr, sizeof *arr * (i+1));`.  Drop the cast and size to the the referenced data.